# Handle a POST request in Azure Function to upload a file to blob storage

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to upload a file via simple Azure function HTTPTrigger in JS and it gives me the following error:

```
[Error] Exception while executing function: Functions.HttpTriggerJS1. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK '[Hidden Credential]' connection string is missing or empty. The Microsoft Azure Storage account connection string can be set in the following ways:
1. Set the connection string named '[Hidden Credential]' in the connectionStrings section of the .config file in the following format <add name="[Hidden Credential]" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http|https;AccountName=NAME;AccountKey=KEY" />, or
2. Set the environment variable named '[Hidden Credential]', or
3. Set corresponding property of JobHostConfiguration.
```

I'm not sure where to find and edit the .config file or add an environment variable. The connection string is already added to the `function.json` file as seen below.

Also, I don't know whether just `context.bindings.outputBlob = req.body;`
 is enough to create a blob in the storage container with `content-type': 'application/octet-stream'`.

index.js:

```
module.exports = function (context, req) {

 context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

 context.bindings.outputBlob = req.body;

 context.res = {

 // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */

 body: "Uploaded " 

 };

 context.done();

};
```

function.json

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "route": "FileUploadNode/{filename}",
      "methods": [
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "outputBlob",
      "path": "CONTAINER-NAME/{filename}",
      "connection": "SOME CONNECTION STRING",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Comment: Your code is enough to create a blob, and @Evandro has provided a nice answer for your connection string problem.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to the **Azure Portal > Your Azure Function App > Platform Features > Application Settings** and add the Storage Account connection string as a *value* and the **SOME CONNECTION STRING** string in your function.json file as the *name*.

You can add it as an **Application Setting** or a custom **Connection String**, either will work fine.

Find more details at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node.